# Increment operator not showing expected result

Tags: c, increment

I am not getting the result I expected.

```
void main(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = x++;
    printf("%d, %d", x, y);
}
```

I am getting `6, 5` as output, but I expected `6, 6`.

Comment: But `6, 5` is the expected result ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to mark one of the answers below as "accepted" if it answers your question. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 4):

You're using the post-increment operator.

The line:

```
int y = x++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int y = x;
x += 1;
```

The increment of `x` occurs after the value of `x` is copied to `y`.

The pre-increment operator is probably what you're looking for, which would be used like:

```
int y = ++x;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
int y;
x += 1;
y = x;
```

which appears to be what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

The `++` operator behaves differently depending where it is.

`y = x++;` will get the value of x and then increment it. (Post-increment)

`y = ++x;` will increment x first, and then give that new value to y.  (Pre-increment)

You're probably looking for pre-increment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the postincrement operator.  It evaluates to the value of the variable **before** it is incremented, which is why `y` contains 5.

For your case you want the preincrement operator.

```
y = ++x:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the post-increment operator (i.e `x++`) and assigned it to `y`, so `y` will be 6 and `x` will be 5.

For your expected output, use the pre-increment operator, like so:

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int y = ++x;
    printf("%d, %d", x, y);
}
```